VBA 7.1 - Is there a way to toggle the "Black & White" property on/off in MS Word Printer Dialog?
I want to create a macro -- or even just a printer preset -- that allows me to turn the "Black & White" property on/off in the MS Word Print Dialog. The property appears in a dialog box for my Canon TR7600 series inkjet as a checkbox right next to the checkbox for "Collated."
PRESET - If I change the settings and "save" a preset, the Black & White on/off value is not saved but others are. In other words, lets say I toggle "off" the Black & White property and, at the same time, toggle on the Double Sided property, then I save that as a new preset. Lets call it "Color Dougle Sided." If I select that preset from the list of presets, it will change the Double Sided property but not the Black & White.
MACRO - When I do something similar while recording a macro I get:
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
    wdPrintDocumentContent, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:=wdPrintAllPages, _
    Collate:=True, PrintToFile:=False, PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, _
    PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0

So most of the important settings but Black & White. (It also ignore some arcane ones that we don't need to discuss here. Suffice it to say that Black & White is not the only orphan.)
I tried just inserting "Black & White:=False" in the list of properties but VBA choked on it.
I also want to do the same thing for the Double-sided property.
Anyone know a way to fudge this? I can't think of a work around and am hoping the collective will have a genius who can do this for me.
I'm in MS Word 16.9, VBA 7.1.

This is very much dependent on the printer driver, not available to vba. Make separate printer driver copies set the way youv want. This is not a code-writing service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Depending on the printer, you may be able to get the desired result by setting Application.Options.PrintDraft = True before printing, then reverting afterwards.
